# Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture

Tags: excel, vba

Please bear with me, I'm new to code, I'm trying to embed an image in an excel file, however it keeps crapping out on me when I run this code. I have searched form after form and cannot find the answer.

```
'Import Image
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As String
Dim img As Object

ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")

    'set img line is highlighted hovering displays a message. img = nothing

    Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=fNameAndPath, Pathlinktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
    With img

       'Move and Resize Image
        img.Select
       Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
       Selection.Left = ActiveSheet.Range("H10").Left
       Selection.Top = ActiveSheet.Range("H10").Top
       Selection.Width = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:O10").Width
       Selection.Height = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:O24").Height

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Width:= **-1** ??

Comment: I will be honest here, width and height were originally set to 1. while grasping at straws I found a post referring to object placement and changed it to -1 hoping that would solve the problem, "deep down inside I knew it would not" but i gave it a shot anyway...

Comment: You didn't say where the error lies, but it looks like the name for your second argument in AddPicture is incorrect.  It should be LinkToFile, not Pathlinktofile.  Btw, using Width:=-1 sets the width to its default size.

Comment: Domenic! You are a life saver! I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested and works:

```
'Import Image
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As String
Dim img As Object


fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")
    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
    With img
       'Move and Resize Image
       .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
       .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("H10").Left
       .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("H10").Top
       .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:O10").Width
       .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:O24").Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, The code you attached is the code I am currently using in my report. I should have been a bit more clear in my heading. I am looking to modify this code so it will embed the image instead of linking the image in the event I am asked to send my Data File "excel File" instead of my .pdf report.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub GetPic()
 Dim fNameAndPath As String
 Dim img As Excel.Shape

 ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
 fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")

 Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
  fNameAndPath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, ActiveSheet.Range("H10").Left, _
  ActiveSheet.Range("H10").Top, ActiveSheet.Range("H10:O10").Width, _
  ActiveSheet.Range("H10:O24").Height)
  img.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

  'Just for fun:
   img.IncrementRotation 45
End Sub
```