# import multiple pictures into Excel and open file on another computer

Tags: excel, vba, image, import

I have managed to pull together some VBA code from other sources (many thanks) to create something that is about 80% complete. However when I send or open my spreadsheet on another computer my pictures do not appear (just a red X).

My research has lead me to use and insert the 
`ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture` method however I am unsure how to build this into my functioning code / where to place this. I have filenames in `Column D` which relate to the stored pictures from my folder. The pictures are loaded into Column C and this allworks perfectly, I have approx 550 jpeg files. However I cannot view the images once it's off my computer

My working code is:

```
Sub InsertPicsr1Reg()
    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    fPath = "\Desktop\test workings\"
    For Each r In Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
        On Error GoTo errHandler
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & r.Value)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Top = Cells(r.Row, 3).Top
                .Left = Cells(r.Row, 3).Left
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Columns(3).Width Then .ShapeRange _
                    .Width = Columns(3).Width
                Rows(r.Row).RowHeight = .ShapeRange.Height
            End With
        End If
errHandler:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & ", " & r.Value
            On Error GoTo -1
        End If
    Next r
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next shp
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Some related posts: [How to insert a picture in excel using VBA](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2013/06/insert-a-picture-in-excel-using-vba/) or [VBA Excel 2010 - Embedding Pictures and Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22073463/8112776) or [Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918683/8112776) or [Shapes.AddPicture Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub InsertPicsr1Reg()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "\Desktop\test workings\"
For Each r In Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
    If r.Value <> "" Then

        With ActiveSheet
            .Shapes.AddPicture fPath & r.Value, _
                msoFalse, msoTrue, _
                .Cells(r.Row, 3).Left, _
                .Cells(r.Row, 3).Top, _
                .Columns(3).Width, _
                .Rows(r.Row).Height
        End With

     end if
   next
end sub
```

Comment: This has worked for me, I am now able to view the pictures on other computers. All I need to do now is to tinker with the width and height of the cells for easy of viewing. Much appreciation Hamed